# sql query to get most recent row - optimized for Vertica DB

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table here that has millions of entries.  The table stores event and each event has a timestamp.  Given some WHERE clause params, I want the most recent event.

This is what we came up with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventTable 
WHERE timestamp_date >= '2012-07-16' AND 
      eventType = 1  AND someOtherField = 'value' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Currently this is taking way too long to return.  Is there a way to alter the SQL to give me what we want a lot faster?  Also, is there a projection strategy for things like this?

thanks
jose

Comment: do u have an index on your timestamp field

Comment: this maybe [interesting](http://www.vertica.com/2010/11/23/life-beyond-indices-the-query-benefits-of-storing-sorted-data/)

Comment: What are the projections you have for this table?

Comment: i have 1 on the date.  i actually wanted to have the projection on the "someOtherField" because there are less entries per "someOtherField" than on date, which has millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want at least one of your projections to be optimized according to the timestamp column in the order by clause. If you do your projections properly, this should be quite fast.

Edit: Just a note of clarification. I didn't mean to imply that the timestamp column should be the only field in the order by clause. Also, as also mentioned in the comments below, a query-specific run on the Database Designer would not be a bad thing in this case. I believe there is an option to optimize for speed. Since you are doing "select *" the output should probably serve as the super and buddy projections.

Comment: what if you have millions of entries per timestamp_date, but less entries for "someOtheField".  Would it then make more sense to have the projections optimized for "someOtherField"?

Comment: First, you can use Database Designer and tell the Designer to do a query specific optimization. Granted, having sample data in for your table would be needed to get good results.

Comment: In lieu of that, of that you could do something like "order by someOtherField, timestamp" or something along those lines. The important part is that if you include the column in the projection's order by clause properly this query should be fast. I would recommend using the Database Designer in your case, but you can always play around and test.